# how to extract this type of data by selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I want to get how many items present in my cart on amazon.

`<span id="nav-cart-count" aria-hidden="true" class="nav-cart-count nav-cart-0 nav-progressive-attribute nav-progressive-content">0</span>`

here,[image] 0 item is present in my cart...

I don't want to use `.text()` because then data is not callable.

Comment: Can we have relevant code ?

Comment: Also not sure why you have mentioned `.text() because then data is not callable.`, is `get_attribute('innerText')` work for you ?

Comment: Hey! With java, I am able to print the count of the number of items of your cart with below code. The same will work fine in python as well.

`driver.findElement(By.className("nav-cart-count")).getText();`